# One droppable area inside another

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have two droppable areas and one of them is inside another. I want to be possible to catch drop event only for the the internal area and prevent the propagation so the external wouldn't get it at all. Is it possible to do?

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Layout Example</TITLE>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#draggable').draggable();
    $('#droppable1').droppable({
        drop: function() {
            console.log('droppable 1')
        }
    });
    $('#droppable2').droppable({
        drop: function() {
            console.log('droppable 2')
        }
    });
});
</SCRIPT>
<style>
#droppable1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 500px;
    background: blue;
}
#droppable2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 100;
    background: red;
}
#draggable {
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    top: 300px;
    width: 100px;
    left: 300px;
    z-index: 200;
}
</style>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div id="droppable1">Droppable 1</div>

<div id="droppable2">Droppable 2</div>

<div id="draggable">Draggable</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here is jsFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/BS3g9/1/).

Try to drag the 'Draggable' box into 'Droppable 2' area. With this implementation 'Droppable 1' area will get the Drop event first and after that it will only go to 'Droppable 2'. What I want is just the 'Droppable 2' get the event.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the events are triggering in this order but here is a workaround if it helps. Just setting a timeout before triggering your event will allow you to check if the event bubbling is complete:

http://jsfiddle.net/BS3g9/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#draggable').draggable();
    $('#droppable1').droppable({
        drop: function() {
            brain.registerDrop(function() {
               console.log("DROPPED 1!");
            });
        }
    });
    $('#droppable2').droppable({
        drop: function() {
            brain.registerDrop(function() {
               console.log("DROPPED 2!");
            });
        }
    });
});

var brain = {
    state : {
        dropAction : function() {},
        dropTimer : null
    },
    registerDrop  : function(cb) {
        brain.state.dropAction = cb;
        if (brain.state.dropTimer) {
            clearTimeout(brain.state.dropTimer);
        }
        brain.state.dropTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            brain.state.dropAction();
        }, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could probably get away with a smaller timeout as well - ~2ms

Comment: Jonathan, not sure that I understand your suggestion... could you share the code with me? The link that you sent doesn't have any changes

Comment: interesting... will think about it. I personally don't like the solutions based on setTimeout, but probably it will work in this case... anyway, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I was able to broke your example... if I register droppable2 before droppable1, this area will never get the event. See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pshenichnov/BS3g9/4/

Comment: That makes sense. My fix was under the assumption that the 2nd layer was at the bottom of the callstack and so waits for the event to bubble before running the callback. Changing the order of registering the events fundamentally changes the callstack. This would mean only running the first event and preventing any subsequent events from running